# Add map layers during runtime ESRI Javascript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I had a look through the **ESRI js API** (version:3/4) and examples on ESRI's page but I couldn't find something like  an "add map layers from ", where the source is any reachable map service, WMS or ESRI Map service or something else.

If I want one I build it myself?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use some JavaScript to take in the URL and create the layer and add it to the map. Something like this:

```
var addLayer = (url) => {
    const layer = new FeatureLayer({
      url: url 
    });
    map.layers.add(layer);
  }
```

Of course you'll have to ask the user to specify the layer type, or detect it from the pattern. [Here's an example](https://codepen.io/gavinr/pen/eLgpva) for Feature Layer only to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the example, the answer then is to build one myself rather than there being a "search for/browse and add layers from this predefined/runtimedefined source" widget ready. That's all I wanted to know : ) Also I shall make sure not to write "Friendly regards" anymore.